# How to dynamically switch between two arrays for attribute in my blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a controller method which retrieves data from a Queue, the queue can have a relationship to either a Guest or a Customer model.

In my blade template I iterate over the Queue and need to display either Guest.Name or Customer.Name depending on which column is populated.

**Controller**

```
$queue = Queue::where('business_id', '=', $business_id);

$customer_bag = $queue->pluck('user_id');
$guest_bag = $queue->pluck('guest_id');

$customers = User::whereIn('id', $customer_bag)->get();
$guests = Guest::whereIn('id', $guest_bag)->get();

return view('myqueue', compact(['queue', 'customers', 'guests']));
```

**Blade Template**

```
@foreach($queue as $quee)
    {{ $customers->find($quee->user_id) ? $customers->find($quee->user_id)->name : $guests->find($quee->guest_id)->name }}
@endforeach
```

When I use this and the guest_id is blank I get an error stating "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object". How can I correctly detect which one to use?

Comment: You are using many things as they are not, you can improve it. First, you're plucking at an object. Second, you're iterating an object, and third, you're not using the foreach at all. The best thing would be to use the foreach correctly and make a ```! is_null($guests->find($quee->guest_id))```

Comment: Sorry the code was wrong, I simplified it and didn’t have the correct object reference in my for loop. I’ve updated.

Comment: hi, did you try my solution?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that one of my test data records didn't have a value in the `guest_id` when it should have, this caused the blade template to fail render.

Answer (score 0):

I think so many problems with your code.

Firstly, `$queue` is `findOrFail()` which returns  a single object data(not array or collection that can be used for foreach.) I think you need to change to `get()`

Also `$customers`  and `$guests` are a collection, so you can not use `find()` method.

Then you didn't define `$quee` in the @foreach, so it's will give error result.

I think this code will return as you expected if you fix above problems:

```
@foreach($queue as $quee)
    {{ \App\Customer::find($quee->user_id)->name ?? \App\Guest::find($quee->guest_id)->name ?? "no name" }}
@endforeach
```

But a better approach is using relation from your queue model:

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
}

public function guest()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Guest::class);
}

public function getNameAttribute()
{
   return $this->customer?$this->customer->name:($this->guest->name??"no name");
}
```

and in the blade view

```
@foreach($queue as $quee)
    {{ $quee->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Why the -1 Vote? Anyway that's the way to go.. to clean it a bit more: `return $this->customer->name ?? $this->guest->name ?? "no name";` And it is the `User` class, not the `Customer` class

Comment: @ChristopheHubert edited. thanks for the advice, I am new using new ternary conditional.

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur This solution is actually even less efficient as would be lazy loading the customer/guest names as it iterates through the queue which means I could have dozens of queries for each name search; whereas in my queue I do this as one two queries after getting the original queue.

Comment: @InvalidSyntax Why you said about efficiency while your source code is not efficient. my second solution is better than your original code. And my solution is about handling when `guest_id` is null or didn't have value. You can use a ternary condition as the above code.